# Vim :E in center window splits vertically automatically

Tags: vim

Vim ~7.2

I've got three vertical windows.

If I give the :E command in the left window the entire window changes into the netrw file explorer.

If I give the :E command in the right window the entire window changes into the netrw file explorer.

But...if I give the :E command in the center window the center window splits horizontally and the top window opens into the netrw file explorer.

Is this default behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help netrw` has this to say:

```
:Explore  will open the local-directory browser on the current file's
          directory (or on directory [dir] if specified).  The window will be
          split only if the file has been modified, otherwise the browsing
          window will take over that window.  Normally the splitting is taken
          horizontally.
```

I would say that your center window is not saved.